# Using ArcGIS Engine with Background Geoprocessing (64 bit)

Tags: arcobjects, geoprocessing, .net, arcgis-engine, 64bit

Could someone suggest how to use ArcGIS Engine Background Geoprocessing (64 bit) in ArcGIS Engine 10.4 ArcObjects console application?

I am using C#, .Net 4.5.2 framework, ArcObjects SDK 10.4 to develop this.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE! :) This isn't a discussion forum, but a focused Q&A format. Please give more details about what you have tried and what doesn't work. If you haven't done so, please take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not actually as complicated as you'd think.

It's simply a matter of installing both the SDK environment (ArcEngine) and the 64bit Background Geoprocessing for ArcEngine. Once that's installed, any tool that you execute in the background will leverage 64bit by default. There' isn't special code you need to have it execute in the 64bit space; it's just used if it's installed.

[Running a tool in the background [java]](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/java/eb1f0fb8-6665-4442-8051-d92e77609acf.htm)

[Executing a tool via async [.net]](https://github.com/Esri/arcobjects-sdk-community-samples/tree/master/Net/Geoprocessing/GPExecuteToolsAsync)

[Executing a tool in the background [.net]](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#4331f99f-f7b5-44bd-9b2a-e99d7cab6310.htm)

Comment: I'm not sure why Esri blocks google from crawling .NET arcobjects help. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#4331f99f-f7b5-44bd-9b2a-e99d7cab6310.htm

Comment: @KirkKuykendall thanks! thats the one I was thinking of. I added it into the answer